# SettingsLogic not working when running unit tests in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, settingslogic

I am getting this error when running some unit tests (using the Test::Unit module included in Ruby/Rails) that call a method that uses some SettingsLogic feature:

> **RuntimeError: Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you
>   really wanted the id of nil, use
>   object_id**

More specifically, I have written some unit test in order to test some methods in my models. These methods use SettingsLogic feature but it seems that something wrong is happening here. I run a test console and checked that Settings class is defined. However, I cannot access my Settings value hash.

```
script/console test
Loading test environment (Rails 2.3.10)
DEPRECATION WARNING: require "activesupport" is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 3. Use require "active_support" instead. (called from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/activesupport.rb:2)
>> Settings
=> Settings
>> Settings.blah
RuntimeError: Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
    from (erb):32
>> exit
```

Whereas in development environment I get:

```
script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.10)
>> Settings
=> Settings
>> Settings.blah
=> {"gadget_type"=>{"alarm_history_table"=>{"max_printable_rows"=>200, "max_visible_rows"=>14, "_id"=>5, "rows_per_page"=>100}, "text"=>{"_id"=>2}, "current_state_table"=>{"max_printable_rows"=>200, "max_visible_rows"=>14, "_id"=>1, "rows_per_page"=>10}, "column_based_history_table"=>{"max_printable_rows"=>200, "max_visible_rows"=>14, "_id"=>6, "rows_per_page"=>100, "related_states"=>{"unit"=>17, "description"=>49}}, "entity_history_table"=>{"max_printable_rows"=>200, "max_visible_rows"=>14, "_id"=>4, "rows_per_page"=>100}, "chart"=>{"_id"=>3}, "access_type"=>{"url"=>1, "file"=>2}}}
>> exit
```

I am running tests manually, i.e. not with rake test but with `ruby unit/my_model_test.rb`

The settings.rb model is the following:

```
class Settings < Settingslogic
  source "#{Rails.root}/config/application.yml"
  namespace Rails.env
end
```

And the application.yml settings file:

```
defaults: &defaults
  blah:
    gadget_type:
      access_type:
        url: 1
        file: 2
      current_state_table:
        _id: 1
        max_visible_rows: 14
        rows_per_page: 10
        max_printable_rows: 200
      text:
        _id: 2
      chart:
        _id: 3
      entity_history_table:
        _id: 4
        max_visible_rows: 14
        rows_per_page: 100
        max_printable_rows: 200
      alarm_history_table:
        _id: 5
        max_visible_rows: 14
        rows_per_page: 100
        max_printable_rows: 200
      column_based_history_table:
        _id: 6
        max_visible_rows: 14
        rows_per_page: 100
        max_printable_rows: 200
        related_states:
          description: <%= Property.find_by_name('description').id %>
          unit:  <%= Property.find_by_name('units').id %>

development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

RUBY VERSION: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]
RAILS VERSION: 2.3.10
SETTINGS LOGIC: 2.0.6
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED**

The problem was the embedded ruby in the yaml:

```
Property.find_by_name('description').id
```

I did not have the properties fixtures so for this reason it failed.